# Passing Task as parameter to be invoked within loop in async method C#

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, parameters, task

I have the following code in LINQPad:

```
async Task Main()
{
    await PrintLoop(Print1());
}

async Task Print1()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Printing!");
}

//Print 2
//Print 3
//etc.

async Task PrintLoop(Task printer, int iterations = 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        await printer;
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why I get the following output:

```
Printing!
```

As opposed to "Printing!" x3.

If I call `Print1()` directly within the loop I get the following output:

```
Printing!
Printing!
Printing!
Printing!
```

Which kind of makes sense but isn't what I want to do. Instead, I would like for `Print1` (or whichever method is passed as `task`) to be invoked `iterations` times.

Can someone help me understand what's up and down here? Thanks!

Comment: Tasks aren't invoked. They are a *promise* that *something* will complete in the future and maybe produce a value. `await` doesn't invoke, it *awaits* the task representing an already running asynchronous operation to complete, without blocking the thread

Comment: As for why you only get one `Printing!` it's because `Print()` is only called once. It never runs asynchronously since it doesn't have any `await` calls or any `Task.Run()` etc. It returns an *already* completed task that's awaited three times by `PrintLoop`, essentially doing nothing

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the explanation. How would I go about creating a proper `PrintLoop` then? One that doesn't simply `await` an already running task but actually invokes and awaits #`iterations` "instances" of the task provided as a parameter?

Comment: If you wanted to call it more than once, you would need to pass an `Action<Task>` rather than a `Task` so that you can invoke it asynchronously.

Comment: @KieranDevlin You mean [`Func<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1). [`Action<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1) is a method that accepts a `Task` as a parameter and returns `void`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yeah my bad, I just saw the method and didnt see a return type so I assumed `Action` but with it being async then you have to return `Task`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the *result* of calling `Print1()` to the method (a `Task`). You aren't passing the method itself. So it's only called once at `Print1()`. When you `await printer;`, it's really just saying "yup, it happened" and moving on.

If you want to pass the method itself, so that it can be called inside `PrintLoop`, then you need to accept a [`Func<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1) (a method that returns a `Task`).

Then you pass the method itself (`Print1`) without calling it (not `Print1()`)

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    await PrintLoop(Print1); //not Print1()
}

async Task Print1()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Printing!");
}

async Task PrintLoop(Func<Task> printer, int iterations = 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        await printer();
    }
}
```